# Using DateTime with linq to return 'Events' on a certain date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, razor, ef-code-first

At the moment my index is grouping events by date and returning how many there are connected with a certain date.
I want to adda browse link which will list the events associated with a date. I can't seem to compare DateTime's in my linq query, everything I try just returns blank.

Here is my model

```
namespace AtAClick.Models
{
    public class WhatsOn
    {

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? end { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public bool CalenderDisplay { get; set; }
    public DateTime? day { get; set; }
    public int whtscount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here are my index and browse controllers

```
public ViewResult Index(WhatsOn model)
    {
        DateTime myDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);

        var datequery =
                        db.WhatsOns.Where(c => c.start > myDate).OrderByDescending(c => c.start).GroupBy(c => c.start).AsEnumerable().Select(
                        sGroup => new WhatsOn
                        {
                            day = sGroup.Key,
                            whtscount = sGroup.Count()
                        });

        return View(datequery);
    }

    public ViewResult Browse(DateTime? day , int? id)
    {         
        var eventsquery = from c in db.WhatsOns
                          where c.start == day
                           select c;

        return View(eventsquery);
    }
```

Thanks!

update:

Hey! Got it working

Here;s my new controller;

```
    public ViewResult Browse(int? id, DateTime? day, DateTime? start)
    {

        var eventsquery = from c in db.WhatsOns where c.start.Value.Day == day.Value.Day select c;

        return View(eventsquery);


    }
```

And what did the trick, in my actionlink in my view....

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Browse", "Browse", new { start=item.start, day=item.day })
```

Thanks for you help!!

Comment: Off Topic, why don't you replace myDate with DateTime.Now?

Comment: eh, I don't know! I thought I had to do it for day, month and year, but thanks for the advice I'll change it once I get this wee problem out of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much wrong with this looking back on it now years later, but just in case someone needs linq help, here is the answer.

public ViewResult Browse(int? id, DateTime? day, DateTime? start)
    {

```
    var eventsquery = from c in db.WhatsOns where c.start.Value.Day == day.Value.Day select c;

    return View(eventsquery);


}
```

And what did the trick, in my actionlink in my view....

```
@Html.ActionLink("Browse", "Browse", new { start=item.start, day=item.day })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both '`start`' and '`day`' are of type `DateTime`, the comparer on them is going to check each bit for a full `DateTime` object. If you're just trying to browse for the day, and not the exact millisecond of a `DateTime`, try:

```
c.start.Value.Day == day.Value.Day
```

It's also a pretty good idea to do some null checking on those nullable fields as well.

Comment: That's still returning nothing, and there's definitely entries as the 'whtscount' property is two. Havew I made a mistake in the model somehow?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not sure why day is a datetime. can you give an example of a few of the objects you have populated in "db.WhatsOns"?

Comment: day groups my entries by date, so it's a collection of DateTimes. If I change 'day' to anything else I can't compare 'start' with it, I have populated all fields in db.WhatsOn if that's what you mean? Apologies if it isn't, I'm just beginning with this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if you could post in the original question some sample data